# When do I need to state the return type of an async function as a future object?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future

I was going over a lesson on async programming with Dart but for some reason I am getting kind of confused. I think I understand the concepts of how you should be using an async function when it may require some time and so instead of blocking and freezing your app you use an async function so that the next code blocks or methods are executed and when the async function is done or ready it executes. (Please let me know if my understanding is flawed)

However, I don't really get the Future<> part. I get it can be used as a return type of an async function because essentially you are saying the function returns a future object for now but let's come back to it when it's completed. But my instructor kind of confused me, sometimes she had a future as the return type and another time she didn't put it and they were both async functions. So now I'm struggling to understand when is it necessary to explicitly state the Future return type even if it is void? Also isn't just using async and wait for a function already create a future object regardless? Any clarification is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you put some code example where you faced the issue

Answer (score 14):

Yes, using the async keyword will make the function automatically return a Future.

It is always better to explicitly declare the return type of a function even for void functions, if not, the compiler will interpret the function as having a dynamic return type.

It will also help/make it easier for the reader to know the return type of the function.

Also, you need to wrap your object in a Future in an async function like so:

```
Future<Object> getObject() async {
  final object = await timeConsumingTask();
  return object;
}
```

If you write it like this without wrapping it:

```
Object getObject() async {
  final object = await timeConsumingTask();
  return object;
}
```

The compiler throws the error: `Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.`

For void functions, it seems that you do not have to wrap the return type in a Future, so something like this is fine:

```
void doSomething() async {
  await timeConsumingTask();
  print('done');
}
```

Comment: Okay so essentially there is no difference between using future<void> and just using void when the function doesn't return anything. Just to clarify then, i should use an async function whenever i have a time consuming task and I want the next functions in the sequence to continue while it works in the background right? Or should i also use an async function if i want to for example authenticate users using firebase so i dont want to go forward until the users are correctly authenticated? Would using an async skip and go to the next function? I've just seen those functions using this format.

Comment: You want to use async/await for firebase auth to let's say go the next screen `await authenticateUser(); goToNextScreen;` The 'await' keyword basically means    that the next line would not execute unless the time consuming task is done. This is especially useful when that next line is dependent on an object that needs to be fetched in a time consuming manner.

Answer (score 8):

Let's consider a method `gatherNewsReports()` which only returns a `Future<String>`. The string value of the `Future` from `gatherNewsReports`. Implementation of `gatherNewsReports`.

```
// Imagine this is a slow method. Takes time to finish
Future<String> gatherNewsReports() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => news);
```

We will go through all possible combinations of method call with `Future` and `async`. The method I am going to make is called `getDailyNewsDigest`

#### Option-1:

One definition of the method might be as with `Future` and `async` given in method call:

```
Future<String> getDailyNewsDigest() async {
  var str = await gatherNewsReports();
  print(str);
  return str;
}
```

Remember that `gatherNewsReports()` which returns a `Future<String>`. We are just returning whatever `gatherNewsReports` returns.

**Usage:**

```
main() async {
  await getDailyNewsDigest();
  print('call done');
}
```

**Output:**

```
<gathered news goes here>
call done
```

Comments: This seems straight forward. You just call the method and await on it. Remember we are using `await` keyword when calling `getDailyNewsDigest` from the `main` method. So, unless we pass `1 second`, i.e, the duration of time it requires the `Future` to execute. If we didn't use the await keyword then the output sequence will be reversed.

#### Option 2

One definition of the method might be as with `Future` given and `async` **NOT** given in method call:

```
Future<String> getDailyNewsDigest() {
  var str = await gatherNewsReports();
  print(str);
  return str;
}
```

This is not valid because you can't call a method with `await`, in this case `gatherNewsReports`. ***This is invalid***.

#### Option-3

We define the method might be with `Future` **NOT GIVEN** and `async` given in method call. Since the return type is going to be `void` we will not return anything (**N.B: If we try to return anything other than a `Future` or a `void` then we get an error**):

```
void getDailyNewsDigest() async {
  var str = await gatherNewsReports();
  print(str);
}
```

This is a valid method definition. Now, since the method is declared as `void` we can't `await` on the `main` method. The updated `main` method.

```
main() async {
  getDailyNewsDigest(); // We can't await on it since return is void
  print('call done');
}
```

**Output:**

```
call done
<gathered news goes here>
```

As you can see since the method `getDailyNewsDigest` is not called without `await` the output is reversed. We are no longer waiting for the `getDailyNewsDigest` to finish.

#### Option-4

We define the method might be with `Future<Void>` instead of `Future<String>` and `async` given in method call:

```
Future<void> getDailyNewsDigest() async {
  var str = await gatherNewsReports();
  print(str);
  return;
}
```

Now in our main method we can use the `await` keyword again for calling `getDailyNewsDigest`.

```
main() async {
  await getDailyNewsDigest(); // We can await on it since return is Future<Void> but don't care on the output since it returns nothing
  print('call done');
}
```

These are 4 combinations I can think of.

As for this:

> But my instructor kind of confused me, sometimes she had a future as
>   the return type and another time she didn't put it and they were both
>   async functions.

Declaring a method with either `Future` means you can await on it, declaring it with `void` means you can't `await` in it. You can of course choose not to `await` on a `Future` if you don't care to do anything with the output of the `Future`. If you write your code in such a way that you don't want anyone to depend on the output of the method, i.e, the `Future` we would otherwise return from the method will be handle d by itself, all we care about is **firing-it-and-continue with our work**; in that case we should define our method with return type `void`.

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean when you say if you declare it with void then you cant await it. Clearly a void async function with await waits for the parts included after await to occur before continuing the function? If the function is defined with async, that means that the next function in the sequence will start working while the async function is also working correct? Can you explain more about how using async functions affects the flow of functions executed?

Comment: If you declare the method, suppose `myMethod`, as `void myMethod() async`, then in main method you can't do `await myMethod()`, you can only do `myMethod()`. You can of course perform `await` functionality from **INSIDE** the method since you declared it await but you can never call the method from outside with an `await`. So if you only call this method then the main method will flow as it is without waiting for the async function to finish.

Comment: declaring the method as `async` does not change the code flow. Only if you `await` on it does. Look at the outputs of option 1 and 3. The outputs are reversed, the only difference is I did not call `await` from the main method.